# amazon s3 version paperclip The specified key does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I got this error suddenly after it was working when I open some of the pdf files

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>cases/invoices/000/000/322/original/ACF267A1-1089-4B2A-8384-6A2A9974AC59.jpeg</Key>
<RequestId>AWHEBB10M1Y7REGC</RequestId>
<HostId>ZDoitl0C4tLuijlOuKsATgShbbw6QSA3lU7Ju8ScV9ikUPmTFfTi0gOdcW9rm5rKoRWHN0Om0AM=</HostId>
</Error>
```

And when I check the aws amazon s3 bucket I notice that theres extra hidden files when I switch the version to true and inside it the files that giving me error

for example here is the link of the file in my website http://mobileimplantlab.s3.amazonaws.com/cases/invoices/000/000/322/original/ACF267A1-1089-4B2A-8384-6A2A9974AC59.jpeg?1666673349

and here is the link in amazon
https://mobileimplantlab.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/cases/invoices/000/000/322/original/ACF267A1-1089-4B2A-8384-6A2A9974AC59.jpeg?versionId=tejD03_M2GYRZ7yfy.diAa28RN4JqmMV

in the model inside case.rb

```
 has_attached_file :invoice
  validates_attachment :invoice, :content_type => { :content_type => %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document) }
```

in paperclip.rb

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

in gemfile

```
gem 'paperclip'

gem 'aws-sdk-s3'
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

in development and production.rb

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
   storage: :s3,
   s3_credentials: {
   bucket: 'mobileimplantlab',
   access_key_id: 'access key',
   secret_access_key: 'secret key',
   s3_region: 'us-west-2',
   }
  }
```

What I am doing wrong?

I cant find the solution anywhere here

Comment: If I understand you correctly, trying to access `ACF2...AC59.jpeg` fails, but trying to access `ACF2...AC59.jpeg?versionId=tejD...mMV`, succeeds? It sounds like the object has been deleted but you have versioning enabled for your Bucket. With versioning enabled, deleting an object doesn't actually delete it but rather creates a new version of that object containing a deletion marker. Attempts to retrieve the object without specifying a version will fail because it's deleted. But you can still retrieve a specific version of the object. Look up `GetObject` vs. `GetObjectVersion`.

Comment: @user3553031 Why it deleted? I didn't delete it. I can see the type of it is delete maker

Comment: You might be able to find how how/when it was deleted by checking your Bucket access logs, if you have those enabled.